# What to do when user choose to unlink

Tags: google-smart-home

What's the flow when user choose to unlink account from developer's own app/website? I understand that developers should at least send a user-delete reqeust to homegraph api(as mentioned in https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/rest/v1/agentUsers/delete), but what else should developers do? Should we revoke the OAuth authorization from our own OAuth server? What's the complete process of account delete from server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user unlinks their account, your webhook will receive a [DISCONNECT](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/intent/disconnect) intent.

```
{
  "requestId": "ff36a3cc-ec34-11e6-b1a0-64510650abcf",
  "inputs": [
    {
      "intent": "action.devices.DISCONNECT"
    }
  ]
}
```

From here you will want to revoke the access token given to Google for that user. On your backend you may also want to ensure that APIs like [Request Sync](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/rest/v1/devices/requestSync) and [Report State](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/rest/v1/devices/reportStateAndNotification) will not be created for that user anymore, as those requests will fail.

But the specifics of what you should do will depend a bit on the larger scope of what your service provides, but any association between Google and that user account is removed and any integration you create should be removed at this point.